# How to organise Elasticsearch indexes with too many dynamic fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a scenario where there are too many groups, and each group has numerous documents with few standard fields and few dynamic fields. So I have created an alias for every group for an index. Now, as these groups grow, these dynamic fields are also increasing. I just hit the default 1000 fields limit.
I plan to create an index for each group to solve too many fields issues, but I will have too many indexes problems.

Please let me know if someone knows a better way to handle this problem.

Comment: What do you do with those fields? Do you need to search on them or only need them for display purposes?

Comment: @Val, Currently, we are searching against all the fields.